# Fast Way To Forward Property Implementation to Property of a member

Tags: c#, properties

I spent another day writing boiler code and I need to find a quicker way.
Not all Interface implementations are trivial but there is one case that seems to be super trivial for me.

Suppose I have a property with a getter and a setter that need to be forwarded to a members property that also has a getter and a setter.
What is the fastest way of writing that?

Here is a compiling example that is close to being minimal.
See in the comment what I would like to write.

```
//Core is unchangeable external code
class Core
{
    public int prop { get; set; }
    public Core() { prop = 42; }
}

//Boilerfun can be modified
interface IBoilderFun
{
    int Prop { get; set; }
}

//This implements the adapter for the boiler special case Core
class CoreBoilerAdapter : IBoilderFun
{
    private Core core;

    public CoreBoilerAdapter(Core core)
    {
        this.core = core;
    }

    public int Prop
    {
        get { return core.prop; }
        set { core.prop = value; }
    }
    //public int Prop { core.prop; } <-- this would be awsome
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IBoilderFun bf = InstanciateBasedOnConfig();
        System.Console.WriteLine(bf.Prop);
    }

    private static IBoilderFun InstanciateBasedOnConfig()
    {
        return new CoreBoilerAdapter(new Core());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resharper has a feature called "Generate delegating members". Otherwise, you could spend a few hours writing a Roslyn-based refactoring.

Comment: Use the `Alt+Insert` key combination to bring up the menu to generate the delegating members for ReSharper.